# elementaryOS on Macbook Air 1.1 (a1237)

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub, macbook

Decided to install Linux, because last supported os is Lion 10.7.5, and now in 2020  I’m out of working browsers. So the question is - Is it possible to install elementary on my old Macbook Air? I read a lot of guides, topics, etc. and have problems with boot. I think that the main problem is - 32 Efi boot which isn’t supported. 
“Try elementary” working perfectly, also installation process is okay, but grub is not working. I tried install without grub using efit, no result.
Is there anyone who installed elementary on 1237? Need help, please(

Upd
Installing via USB
System: core2duo, 2gb ram, intel graphics gma 3100

Comment: What does your EFI stub menu look like? Can you boot from live media and issue 'efibootmgr -v' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved
Steps:
Remove refit(mac hd/efi) if it was installed.
Install refind.
Enter live usb with linux on it using refind bootloader, when grub appear press “e” and type “nomodeset” after “splash” then f10.
Install linux alongside mac os, (or else using only “/“ and swap if you want)
After installation refind will be replaced by grub2.
In grub choose os that you want.
Done.

But no wifi)))

Upd: after using eOS at about a half an hour, updated everything, installed some apps. Performance is okay, i can now watch youtube in 720 without lags. Sensors: cpu temperature at 63-65 C’ no apps opened. Sometimes system freezes when 3 and more apps opened (cpu 90-100% use). No issues about RAM, whatever i do only 60% use, swap use only 1% of it’s capacity (2Gb) Will try Lubuntu.